# В чём разница между адресами "0.0.0.0:11000" и"127.0.0.1:11000"?

Tags: c#, linux, сервер

В общем столкнулся с странной ситуацией. Поднимаю сервер на СИшарп.

Вот сам сервер назовём его "базовая" версия:

```
// SocketServer.cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace SocketServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Устанавливаем для сокета локальную конечную точку
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("172.16.8.169");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

            // Создаем сокет Tcp/Ip
            Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Назначаем сокет локальной конечной точке и слушаем входящие сокеты
            try
            {
                sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                sListener.Listen(10);

                // Начинаем слушать соединения
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ожидаем соединение через порт {0}", ipEndPoint);

                    // Программа приостанавливается, ожидая входящее соединение
                    Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                    string data = null;

                    // Мы дождались клиента, пытающегося с нами соединиться

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                    data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                    // Показываем данные на консоли
                    Console.Write("Полученный текст: " + data + "\n\n");

                    // Отправляем ответ клиенту\
                    string reply = "Спасибо за запрос в " + data.Length.ToString()
                            + " символов";
                    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
                    handler.Send(msg);

                    if (data.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") > -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Сервер завершил соединение с клиентом.");
                        break;
                    }

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А вот моя "изменённая" версия:

```
// SocketServer.cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;


using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SocketServer
{

  ...

    class Program{
        // функция запуска (старт)
        static void Main(string[] args){
            // тут устанавливаем глобальные датчики
            R2CPU_t r2cpu_t = new R2CPU_t();
            r2cpu_t.init_ok = false; // датчик инициализации первичных настроек

            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("172.16.8.169");
            // IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPAddress ipAddr = (Dns.Resolve(IPAddress.Any.ToString())).AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

            // Создаем сокет Tcp/Ip *  
            //Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Socket sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // датчик
            bool dachik_ruk = false;
            // Назначаем сокет локальной конечной точке и слушаем входящие сокеты
            try{
                sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                sListener.Listen(10);

                // Начинаем слушать соединения
                while (true){
                    Console.WriteLine("Ожидаем соединение через порт {0}", ipEndPoint);

                    // Программа приостанавливается, ожидая входящее соединение
                    Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                    string data = null;

                    // Мы дождались клиента, пытающегося с нами соединиться

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                    data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

                    // рукопожатие. Показываем данные на консоли
                    Console.Write("Полученный текст: " + data + "\n\n");
                    if(data != null)
                        dachik_ruk = true;

                    if(dachik_ruk == true){
                        Console.Write("Второе рукопожатие: " + data + "\n");
                        // Тут считывание и проверка data
                        // так что тут заполни дальше
                        var prog_t = new Program();
                        prog_t.Conect_work(); 
                    }


                    // Отправляем ответ клиенту
                    string reply = "Спасибо за запрос в " + data.Length.ToString() + " символов";

                    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
                    handler.Send(msg);

                    if (data.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") > -1){
                        Console.WriteLine("Сервер завершил соединение с клиентом.");
                        break;
                    }

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());}

            finally{Console.ReadLine();}
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске "базовой" версии :

```
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb/TCP_CP# mono SocketServer_old.exe
Ожидаем соединение через порт 0.0.0.0:11000

comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ nmap -p 11000 172.16.8.169

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-11 11:42 MSK
Nmap scan report for 172.16.8.169
Host is up (0.0017s latency).

PORT      STATE SERVICE
11000/tcp open  irisa

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

При запуске "изменённой" версии:

```
root@R2CPU:/mnt/usb/TCP_CP# mono SocketServer.exe
Ожидаем соединение через порт 127.0.0.1:11000

comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ nmap -p 11000 172.16.8.169

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-11 17:20 MSK
Nmap scan report for 172.16.8.169
Host is up (0.0014s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
11000/tcp closed irisa

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.20 seconds
```

**Вот совершенно не могу понять что не так, ведь по сути соединение по сети одно и тоже а вот адрес разный (0.0.0.0:11000, 127.0.0.1:11000) 0_о**

Думаю что проблема возможна в линуксе ( из-за sudo ) ибо как мне сказал "человек", у него всё включилось на винде по крайней мере telnet-ом он всё спокойно "позванивал" и порт у него работал (но также признаюсь это всё с его слов, именно "монитор" его, я не видел).

Comment: `при аналогичном “коде”` я мож чего то не понял, но в первом случае вы просто берете первый попавшийся ip из `Dns.GetHostEntry`, а во втором  первый попавшийся ip из `Dns.Resolve`.  Причем значение аргументов отличаются.

Comment: "слушать адрес 127.0.0.1" — это значит "слушать только данный адрес 127.0.0.1", а "слушать адрес 0.0.0.0" — это значит "слушать все доступные адреса". потому и получаете, что если ваш сервер слушает конкретный адрес "127.0.0.1", то адрес "172.16.8.169" никто не слушает.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin можете оформить как ответ ??? заменил строку с             `IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);` на `IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @aleksandr barakin-у 
Он пояснил что :

**127.0.0.1 - Внутренний адрес, в пределах одного ПК**.

> по сути компьютер слушал себя

**0.0.0.0 - является не маршрутизируемым мета-адресом, используемым для обозначения недопустимой, неизвестной или не применимой цели (нет конкретного адресатора).**

> Слушал всех кто обратиться по адресу "172.16.8.169"

После это го я заменил строку с `IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);` на `IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);`

Всё заработало :3

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 (А так-же 0.0.0, 0.0 и даже просто 0) -- адрес **всех** локальных интерфейсов, включая localhost(127.0.0.1)Вот смотрите, у меня веб интерфейс CUPS забинден на 631 порт интерфейса localhost с адресом 127.0.0.1, а так-же есть nginx забинденый на 80-й порт интерфейса 172.19.76.157, но и к тому и другому я могу обратиться, с локального хоста, по адресу 0.0.0.0 (0) и соответствующим портом.

[image: zero ip]